# Line comments in Pycharm

Tags: python, comments, pycharm

Hi when I comment out a line in Pycharm using the ctrl+slash keyboard shortcut, I get

```
# code
```

but instead I want

```
##Code
```

like in IDLE.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [register a new file type](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/creating-and-registering-file-types.html) and at the time of registration specify comment characters.  You need to reassign *.py to this new type from the default `Python` file type that comes with installation.

Step by step procedure:

1. `Ctrl+Alt+S` to open [File Types](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/file-types.html) dialogue.
2. `Alt+Insert` (or click on `+`) to create a new file type
3. In the new File Type dialogue for `Syntax Highlighting` -> `Line comment:` provide `##`
4. Provide rest of the details (including Name and Description) as needed and click `OK`.
5. Select the newly created File Type and in `Registered Patterns` section click `+` to add a wildcard.
6. In `Add wildcard` dialogue box enter `*.py` and click `Ok`
7. Since *.py is already assigned to the default type you will be asked to confirm `Reassign wildcard`.  Do so.
8. `Apply` and `Ok`

Note: We have to do all this because we can not edit default file types and `Python` is a default file type.

Now, open a Python file (`.py` extension) and check `Ctrl+Slash` on any line.  You should now see `##` prepended to the line.

Comment: Thanks but it changed the colour scheme of the code for some reason and I can't seem to change it.

Comment: Did you try Color and Fonts?

Comment: I tried tweaking the Color & Fonts settings but it didn't work. I think it's because pycharm doesn't recognize my code as a Python code because it thinks I'm using a new format.

Comment: Edit your newly created File Type and add keywords(you can have 4 sets of them). Then go to Fonts and Colors->Custom and change the colors of keyword1 to keyword4 to the color of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Slash on any line comments the line i.e. **Ctrl + /**